# StrContains function arguments shows error "Invalid command" for variable

Tags: installation, nsis

I am trying to use NSIS StrContains command.

According to the wiki (https://nsis.sourceforge.io/StrContains) its arguments are following:
`${StrContains} "$result_var" "Needle" "Haystack"`

and example is following:

`${StrContains} $0 "Dirt" "Dirty deeds done dirt cheap"`

But when I try to use this function the compiler shows me an error:

*Invalid command: $ContainsText*

I tried to change variable to stack $0, but result is the same.
Seem that the problem is in arguments, but arguments reordering does not helps. Including variable to quotes also does not have any effect.

I used NSIS 3.01, then updated to the latest version 3.04 - result is the same.

Here is my test *.nsi file:

```
;Include Modern UI
  !include "MUI2.nsh"
; Include for String commands
  !include "LogicLib.nsh"
;--------------------------------
;General

  ;Name and file
  Name "Basic Test"
  OutFile "Basic.exe"

  ;Default installation folder
  InstallDir "C:\temp"

  ;Request application privileges
  RequestExecutionLevel user

  ; import functions
  !define StrContains

;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings
  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
;--------------------------------
;Pages
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
;--------------------------------
;Languages
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections

Var ContainsText

Section "Dummy Section" SecDummy

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  ;set 5 as initial value
  StrCpy $ContainsText "5"
  MessageBox MB_OK "Initial value: $ContainsText"

  ; check if inst dir contains 'temp'
  ; According to https://nsis.sourceforge.io/StrContains
  ; ${StrContains} "$result_var" "Needle" "Haystack"
  ${StrContains} $ContainsText $INSTDIR "temp"
  MessageBox MB_OK "Cmp result: $ContainsText"

  ;Create uninstaller
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Section
Section "Uninstall"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
SectionEnd
```

I expect that first argument is a result variable, second - original string, third - searching substring.
StrContains variable should be 'test' as a result, but this does not compile.

Please help me to understand why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei.

It looks like you have the arguments in the wrong order. Also, you were correct in changing the variable to $0.

The Usage is:

```
${StrContains} "$result_var" "Needle" "Haystack"
```

where `"$result_var"` =$0, `"Needle"` = "temp" (the Needle you are looking for), and `"Haystack"` = $INSTDIR (the Haystack you are looking through).

So, instead of:

```
${StrContains} $ContainsText $INSTDIR "temp"
```

Try this:

```
${StrContains} $0 "temp" $INSTDIR
```

Comment: The compiler firstly says that the problem is in $ContainsText variable. Changing the arguments should not effect the compiler, just the result.

Comment: You have to use one of the `Register` variables, like `$0, $1`, etc, in place of the `$ContainsText` variable The` ${StrContains}` function returns the result in the `Register` variable. See [NSIS Scripting Reference](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html), 4.2.2, for details.

Comment: Did you able to solve this problem? Me facing same issue where using `$0` throws me `Invalid command: "$0"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently.

Initially, it was throwing `Invalid command: "$0"`. Later I learned that an undefined `${StrContains}` causing this trouble.

The documentations are very unclear, I was hoping to include/define a `StrContains` class-file in my script-file that should work. But none worked so far. I have seen very old discussions where `!include StrContains.nsh` been called - but that does not work anymore with the recent version of NSIS.

Finally what has worked this for me is to add the complete "Function Code" from the `StrContains` [documentation](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/StrContains) page. I didn't expect this nor it was clear from the documentation. But this worked for me, and I able to call `${StrContains}` way in my script file.

Comment: Where do you add the StrContains function code?

Comment: Just added the full stack of StrContains method in the main build NSIS script-file.

Comment: What @SantanuKarar meant is to copy the whole Function Code into your NSIS file.

`<the whole code>
!define StrContains '!insertmacro "_StrContainsConstructor"'`